# Como personalizar barra de rolagem no Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Possuo um combo select multiple que não pode ocupar muito espaço vertical, então o ideal seria poder descer o scroll com aquela setinha tradicional para navegar de 1 em 1 item pra baixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem alguma forma de forçar o scroll tradicional, com javascript/jquery e/ou css, ou então no próprio html?

OBS: Chamo de tradicional qualquer estilo de barra de rolagem que possua o botão na parte inferior e superior para o usuário clicar e subir/descer linha a linha.

Comment: A barra de rolagem principal do meu chrome é assim!

Comment: O que você define como "tradicional"? A barra de rolagem padrão do sistema operacional?

Comment: @utluiz: É ai que tá, essa barra não é nada favorável nesse caso. Preciso daquele botão pro usuário clicar. Mas no Chrome não tem, ele renderiza tudo assim.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté : expliquei na pergunta.

Comment: Ok, está mais claro agora. A versão Canary do Chrome já possui estes botões novamente então deve chegar ao Chrome estável em breve. Se precisar disto imediatamente, deve ser possível fazê-lo estilizando os pseudo-elementos `::-webkit-scrollbar-*`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pesquisei e encontrei uma solução. Descobri que é possivel personalizar a barra com essas propriedades CSS:

Definindo propriedades:

**Da barra de rolagem no geral:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{width:15px; }
```

**Dos botões (cima/baixo):**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button{background-color:#bfbfbf; height:15px;}
```

**Do fundo que fica atrás da barra de rolagem:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {background-color:#e4e4e4;}
```

**Da barra de rolagem na vertical:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical{background-color:#bfbfbf; border-top:1px solid #a4a4a4; border-bottom:1px solid #a4a4a4}
```

**Da barra de rolagem na horizontal:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{background-color:black;}
```

**Do botão inferior(da barra vertical):**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment {background-image:url("Imagens/seta-baixo.png");}
```

**Do botão superior(da barra vertical):**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement {background-image:url("Imagens/seta-cima.png");}
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: João, se possível, poste uma imagem do resultado.

Comment: Alguma compatibilidade com outros navegadores? Eu lembro de quando a molecada fazia um cursinho de HTML e montava sites no FrontPage e enchia o código com instruções que mudavam a cor da barra de rolagem. Daí o Firefox começou a se popularizar e essa febre felizmente passou.

Answer (score 0):

O jScrollPane pode resolver seu problema.

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Veja o exemplo para o que precisa no link a seguir:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/arrows.html